# null value in column "comment_id" of relation "blog_comment" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, view

When attempting to create an application for comments in my Django blog, I get the "null value in column "comment_id" of relation "blog_comment" violates not-null constraint" error listed above. For the view of the page, I am using a Detail View with a FormMixin. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any assistance is appreciated.

The full error message

```
IntegrityError at /post/7/
null value in column "comment_id" of relation "blog_comment" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, dafsdfa, sdfasdfasdf, sdfadfa, 2021-03-10 15:03:11.283567+00, null).
```

views.py

```
class DetailPostView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "posts"
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk})
```

Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        labels = {"author": "Author", "title": "Title", "content": "Comment"}

        fields = ["author", "title", "content"]
```

Comment: should that comment field in Comment actually be "post = models.ForeignKey(Post)". Also, in your ModelForm you aren't including the post field to actually put into the referenced field in the Comment model.

Comment: Hello Trent, Are you suggesting I change the field in the models.py from "comment" to "post" instead. I didn't think that mattered since I am just naming a row that is tied to my other model called Post. As for your ModelForm comment, I am not sure I understand what you mean exactly. Do you mean i need to add post to the fields list?

Comment: If these are dumb questions, my bad, just genuinely confused.

Comment: That's right. You "should" change the name on the model because it's not actually a comment, it's a post. Second part yes, you need to add post to the fields list otherwise the form will have no idea what post to apply the comment to.

Comment: Thank you. Trent, your suggestion worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments. Trent pointed out that I wasn't referencing which post to comment on in my forms.py.